# How can i prevent cgi-bin of being automatically created?

Tags: web, cpanel, cgi-bin

A `cgi-bin` folder was automatically created in the directory for my site. I don't use that folder at all because I don't need it. I don't know how to permamently delete it.

How can I achieve that? It creates itself every now and then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a webmastering question and should be moved to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you create the site (ie. cPanel account) through WHM? There is a "CGI Privilege" for each cPanel account that can be enabled/disabled through WHM - this might control the creation of the `cgi-bin` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using cPanel, edit `/etc/bashrc` and comment out these lines:

```
if [ ! -e ~/public_html/cgi-bin ]; then
mkdir -p ~/public_html/cgi-bin
fi
```

You may need your administrator or web host to do this if you don't have access.